# Continuous image loading/processing & display on button click (in Swing)

Tags: java, image, swing, processing, swingworker

I have trouble with continuous image loading&processing&display in Swing:

Below there is simple case where clicking a button causes my program to grab frame from webcam and then display this picture in jlabel. It works as it should, but i have to consecutively click this "Start" button in order to get new image(frame) shown.

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
           displayed_img = this.getPIC_COLOR(player);       
           img_field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(displayed_img));
        }
```

Im more demanding and i would like to make some image processing during live video stream, therefore i need to "grab" & "show" my frames continuously. You might say that i can just launch webcam stream, but it is not what i want to achieve since i'm about to implement some threshholding/etc. functions which will modify my image on-fly. Therefore i need to perform this grabbing&processin&display as fast as possible (delay is a no-no since i want to achieve something like 10 fps including image processing). Despite the fact that i delay is utterly undesirable i tried to make some Thread.sleep however it didnt work.

Simple while(true) /* presented below */ does not work, my program "hangs" and not even single frame is displayed, although in debugger it keeps working over and over.

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        while(true){
            displayed_img = this.getPIC_COLOR(player);
            //threshholding & further processing...
            img_field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(displayed_img));               
        }            
    }
```

just in case getPIC_COLOR() was required, i paste it below:

```
public BufferedImage getPIC_COLOR(Player player){

            FrameGrabbingControl frameGrabber = (FrameGrabbingControl)player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
            Buffer buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();
            Image img = (new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat()).createImage(buf));
            BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g = buffImg.createGraphics();            
            g.drawImage(img, null, null);

            return buffImg;
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

---

Ok, after some reading i managed to write some SwingWorker Code:

```
private void SingleFrameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   SwingWorker<Void, BufferedImage> worker = new  SwingWorker<Void, BufferedImage>() { 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {

        while (!isCancelled()) {
            displayed_img = getPIC_COLOR(player);
            publish(displayed_img);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);  

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }            
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List mystuff) {

        Iterator it = mystuff.iterator();            
        while (it.hasNext()) { 
            img_field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(displayed_img));
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(displayed_img, "png", new File("c:\\testimg.jpg"));                        
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TestCAMGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        infoBAR.setText("FINISHED");
    }
};
   worker.execute();
```

}

Now what seriously bothers me is the fact that my `img_field` is not updated in swing, although `ImageIO.write` present in `process` works, and image is "redrawn" on C:\ with MAD speed ("mad speed" is highly desirable). Moreover my GUI is still frozen even though i created this swing worker thread...

btw i also tried to "sleep" this saving thread for a second, however my GUI hangs even with this additional sleep

Now some explanations about my code:

- `doInBackground()` returns void, as i dont need to return anything, since i assume this process will run till cancelled (which is unlikely to happen, unless program is closed).
- inside `process()` i've included try/catch block with `ImageIO.write` just to make sure my thread launched and works
- i didnt use 'SwingUtilities.invokeLater' due to fact that browsing guides/tutorials i've read that it is better to  use SwingWorker in my case
- What bothers me furthermore: in `process` i operate on list which enlarges... i dont need that, i just need a single element and thats all. So is there a way to collect single object from `doInBackground()`? making list seems memory waste for me. Or maybe i should `clear()` the list at the end of `process()`? (in order to reduce memory allocated)

Any further hints are appreciated.

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded?  Running an infinite while loop in the Swing event dispatching thread is definitely not healthy.

Comment: hmm, nope it isnt, i initially thought about multi-threading, but this field is something i know nothing about (therefore i did not engaged in such advanced programming) apparently it seems in such case it is mandatory, am i right? Nonetheless, i only want to perform this frame gram + process + display results, so i did not considered it necessary, although you need to know that "few" lines before i launch a webcam stream, guess it might have some effect on my infinite loop?

Comment: You basically need to understand multi-threading to do Swing.  Some methods **must** run on the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT) and others **must not** run on the EDT.  In your case `setIcon` must run on the EDT since it modifies a Swing component, but the while loop must be on another thread (it's possible).  I don't know javax.media so I'm not sure if `getPIC_COLOR` should run on the EDT or not.

Comment: Thanks for useful tips, guess i'll have to involve in multithread stuff ;)

Comment: @Marian there are some contraproductice steps, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523623/gracefull-exception-handling-in-swing-worker/6524300#comment-7689675 and on the left side are Related threads, and separate Action from JButton, SwingWorker, save Image/IconImage to the separeted viod, class ...

Comment: i've browsed most of those related articles during writing my code, it seems that ~somehow my background thread is working, however it completely locks GUI. I've changed my worker to inner class and the only case when GUI is actually repainting is when i start to browse C:\\testimg.jpg file (i get exception in program about acces violation, however frame is redrawn sucessfully, I guess its redrawn only because it cant be saved and exception appears).  `process(List mystuff)` is `process(List<BufferedImage> mystuff)`. However i cannot find way to unlock GUI to observe smooth program work.

Comment: my worker class code on pastebin: (couldnt impement that much in comment) http://pastebin.com/2856zUXf  i execute on `buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEven evt) { (mytask=new Worker()).execute();  }`   [terribly sorry for double comment but they are limited]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not run any kind of infinite loop of that form in a method that is called from an event (unless you explicitly intend to hang your user interface, which would be odd to say the least).

You should run your frame grab in a separate thread, and then use something like [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to display it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help, guess I'll have to browse some multithread guides/tutorials to get this thing further.